# some icons are not displayed in flutter app

Tags: flutter

I was trying a web app, some icons are being displayed in chrome but not in the android-emulator.

```
class Pagine extends StatelessWidget {
  const Pagine({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      children: const [
        TableRow(children: [
          Icon(Icons.android_rounded),
          Icon(
            IconData(0xf04be, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'), // icons.apple  <- does not show this icon
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.apple_rounded, // does not show this icon
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
          Icon(Icons.web),
          Icon(Icons.desktop_windows_rounded),
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: web app]

[image: android app]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin   [font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter/install)
this plugin provides thousands of free icons I think this will help you.

```
font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0

import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.search),
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, this plugin works fine, but i wanted to know why my code doesn't work